# How to use C# to get column's description of Sql Server 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I can use " Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table " in C# to get a table columns of a Sql Server 2005 database.

I have got the column.Name, but how can I get the column's Description in C#?

I have saw the link: [SQL Server: Extract Table Meta-Data (description, fields and their data types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types)

But how can I use C# "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" dll to get a column's Description?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say your Smo.Table object is named t.

This will get the description:

```
t.Columns["ProductID"].ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value
```

Comment: Let there be light

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the result from the query described in the link you gave?

Comment: I have saw the link. But how can I just get a specific column's description in C# ? For example, I want to get the column "ProductId" 's description in the "Product" table of "Northwind" Database.