# Create CSV with specific column via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I would like to create a csv file based with a basic query from SQL Server, however I should create the column names in the first row and in the second row the column description, how can I do? my problem is to create the second line because it is not defined by a query and I have no idea how to proceed to say what to write in the first two lines.

Do you have some examples?

For now I wrote this:

```
protected void ExportCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))

    {    
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers"))

        {    
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())

            {    
                cmd.Connection = con;

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())

                {    
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.

                    string csv = string.Empty;     

                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)

                    {    
                        //Add the Header row for CSV file.

                        csv += column.ColumnName + ',';

                    }   

                    //Add new line.

                    csv += "\r\n";     

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)

                    {    
                        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)

                        {    
                            //Add the Data rows.

                            csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';    
                        }     

                        //Add new line.

                        csv += "\r\n";

                    }     

                    //Download the CSV file.

                    Response.Clear();

                    Response.Buffer = true;

                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");

                    Response.Charset = "";

                    Response.ContentType = "application/text";

                    Response.Output.Write(csv);

                    Response.Flush();

                    Response.End();

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This screenshot shows that what I would like in the second line:

[image]

Comment: I guess [this SO post should help...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098630/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-get-columns-description-of-sql-server-2005)

Comment: the description is not in my database but I could put it in an array, I have no idea how to proceed to create the second line

Comment: It might be worth posting what you have so far, as it's hard to work out exactly what your question is.  For example, you've said that you don't know what to write in the second line - what's the first?

Comment: @pm_2: he mentioned that the first are the column names. The second should be each column's description. That is a property which you can set in sql-server management studio to describe what this column stores.

Comment: unfortunately the second line I have to write I can not modify the database, I only have read permissions:)

Comment: @TimSchmelter you can set those properties up... I suppose my question is: is that what he's looking for (if so, I believe you can access it using the DataColumn.ExtendedProperties collection)   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.extendedproperties.aspx

Comment: Do not use Comma directly, use it via environment variable to avoid localization issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to use a `UNION` statement here; for example:

```
SELECT Hdr1, Hdr2, Hdr3
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'description1', 'description 2', 'description 3'
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM MYTABLE
```

EDIT:

From C#, you could do something like:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{    
    //Add the Header row for CSV file.
    csv += column.ColumnName + ',';
}   

//Add new line.
csv += Environment.NewLine;     
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    csv += $"{column.ExtendedProperties["Description"]},";
}

//Add new line.
csv += Environment.NewLine;
```

Obviously, this depends on your configuring the extended properties - if you haven't then you'll need a place to get the column description from

Comment: I think that I write also logic c#

Comment: great but how do I put it in the second line?

Comment: Do you mean where should this snippet go in relation to the rest of your code?

Comment: exactly, Exactly where should I put it

Comment: I've updated my question to place it in the correct position.

Comment: thanks! I would like to vote positively but I do not have sufficient points :(