# How to retrieve column description of a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using C# Asp.Net in my project , I have added description for all the columns of a particular table in SQL Server.

Column Name  -->   Description

cAppNo    -->      Application No

cFName  -->        First Name

cMName  -->        Middle Name

So my requirement is that I need to fill a dropdownlist with column descriptions of the columns , so how can I retreive description.Is it possible at all?
Can I use Linq.Also if I know know the description of a particular column , is it possible to retrieve the actual value of that column based on the description.I mean the value suppose in column cFName is John , so how canI get that value if I know the decription.Please let me know if that can be achieved.Any suggestions are welcome.Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types

Comment: @ThitLwinOo , how do I retrieve it in c# , is it possible ,can this be done using Linq.

Comment: Hi, it should be done same as normal data retireving process. Get connection to DB, then execute sql script (select desired columns list).