# SQL Server meta data table and column descrption

Tags: sql, sql-server, system-tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: Extract Table Meta-Data (description, fields and their data types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types)

I just like to ask if there is a way to programmatically retrieve table and column descriptions from SQL Server 2008? These are the descriptions that you can enter when using the UI.

And if so, is there a way to programmatically update them as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean junk added through sp_addextendedproperty? IMHO your schema should be documented outside of the database (and should involve source control).

Comment: sys.tables and sys.columns are you new friends

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the "descriptions" you set using MSSMS's UI you need to query sys.extended_properties.

Start by doing `select * from sys.extended_properties` and read some records in the value column to know what I mean (you'll find previously set descriptions there). You will later need to do some joins with sysobjects (I guess) in order to know which description belongs to which table and you'll be ready to go. Search in google for more info if you're confused =)

Also, try this:

```
select * from sys.extended_properties
inner join sysobjects on sys.extended_properties.major_id = sysobjects.id
```

The 'value' column and the second 'name' column (which belongs to sysobjects) are what you're looking for.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get the description data, you need to fiddle with sysobjects/syscolumns

```
SELECT          u.name + '.' + t.name AS [table],
            td.value AS [table_desc],
                c.name AS [column],
                cd.value AS [column_desc]
FROM            sysobjects t
INNER JOIN  sysusers u
    ON          u.uid = t.uid
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties td
    ON          td.major_id = t.id
    AND         td.minor_id = 0
    AND         td.name = 'MS_Description'
INNER JOIN  syscolumns c
    ON          c.id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
    ON          cd.major_id = c.id
    AND         cd.minor_id = c.colid
    AND         cd.name = 'MS_Description'
WHERE t.type = 'u'
ORDER BY    t.name, c.colorder
```

some info can be found out at

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```