# easiest way to add a SQL column through VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

What i want to do is first check if a certain column already exists in a table and if not add it. I want to implement this through visual basic. If somebody took a little time to comment and briefly explain each step i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know SQL?  If so you can use ADO.NET to hard code an sql statement into your VB.Net code

Comment: actually, ado.net is exactly what i have to use. do tell

Comment: have you tried to write any code yet?

Comment: i wrote something that gets me data from a table. but all the "variables" and commands SQL uses in VB are SF for me at the moment, i do not know what are the core instruction or whatever i have to use

Comment: ssooooo how do i do it?

Comment: duplicate to users other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14971973/1606972

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to determine if a column exists: either try to use it and catch the error if it doesn't exist, or read the metadata from the database see [SQL Server: Extract Table Meta-Data (description, fields and their data types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types)

Once you know that you need to add the column you use the ALTER TABLE command to add the column to the table.

Comment: Within VB you can also open an empty recordset and iterate through the columns collection. But you could certainly write a stored procedure to do all of Peter Wooster's suggestion. Please note that database table changes from application code is generally not considered a good design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is vb.net script to check **if** column exist, **if not**, create it..

*''' **summary**
''' Checks to see if a table exists in Database or not.
''' 
''' Table name to check
''' Connection String to connect to
''' Works with Access or SQL
'''*

```
Public Function DoesTableExist(ByVal tblName As String, ByVal cnnStr As String) As Boolean
    ' For Access Connection String,
    ' use "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" &
    ' accessFilePathAndName

' Open connection to the database
Dim dbConn As New OleDbConnection(cnnStr)
dbConn.Open()

' Specify restriction to get table definition schema
' For reference on GetSchema see:
' http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934(VS.80).aspx

Dim restrictions(3) As String
restrictions(2) = tblName
Dim dbTbl As DataTable = dbConn.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)

If dbTbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    'Table does not exist
    DoesTableExist = False
Else
    'Table exists
    DoesTableExist = True
End If

dbTbl.Dispose()
dbConn.Close()
dbConn.Dispose()
```

End Function

*''' 
''' Checks to see if a field exists in table or not.
''' 
''' Table name to check in
''' Field name to check
''' Connection String to connect to
''' 
'''*

Public Function DoesFieldExist(ByVal tblName As String, _
                               ByVal fldName As String, _
                               ByVal cnnStr As String) As Boolean
    ' For Access Connection String,
    ' use "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" &
    ' accessFilePathAndName

```
' Open connection to the database
Dim dbConn As New OleDbConnection(cnnStr)
dbConn.Open()
Dim dbTbl As New DataTable

' Get the table definition loaded in a table adapter
Dim strSql As String = "Select TOP 1 * from " & tblName
Dim dbAdapater As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, dbConn)
dbAdapater.Fill(dbTbl)

' Get the index of the field name
Dim i As Integer = dbTbl.Columns.IndexOf(fldName)

If i = -1 Then
    'Field is missing
    DoesFieldExist = False
Else
    'Field is there
    DoesFieldExist = True
End If

dbTbl.Dispose()
dbConn.Close()
dbConn.Dispose()
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim connString As String = "Data Source=NameOfMachine\InstanceofSQLServer;Initial Catalog=NameOfDataBase;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim MyCol As String = "NameOfColumn"
    Dim MyTable As String = "[NameOfTable]" ' or "[Name Of Table]" use brackets if table name contains spaces or other illegal Characters
    Dim MySql As String = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" & vbCrLf &
"WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" & MyTable & "' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" & MyCol & "')" & vbCrLf &
"BEGIN" & vbCrLf &
"ALTER TABLE [dbo]." & MyTable & " ADD" & vbCrLf & "[" & MyCol & "] INT NULL ;" & vbCrLf & "END"

    Try
        ' MsgBox(MySql)- this msg box shows the Query so I can check for errors- Not required for code.
        Dim dbConn = New SqlConnection(connString)' Note ConnString must be declared in the form class or within this Sub. Connstring is your connection string
        Dim dbCmd = New SqlCommand(MySql, dbConn)
        dbConn.Open()
        dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'MessageBox.Show("Ready To Load Addendums")

        dbConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("We've encountered an error;" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Comment: Sorry the line "MessageBox.show("Ready to load Addendums") is also not required.