# adding a column to a SQL table in VB using ADO.NET commands

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am interested in a minimal set of instructions that allow me to add a column into an existing table in visual basic using ado.net components. My database is made in sql server. I would greatly appreciate a practical commentary to the code as that works best for me

edit 1

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim connString As String = "Data Source=THE_SHOGUNATE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=le_database;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT denumire FROM Reparatii", conn)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(reader)
        ListBox1.DataSource = dt
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "denumire"
        conn.Close()

        conn.Open()
        Dim comm As New SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE reparatii ADD durata_executie INT", conn)

        conn.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's a set of instructions meant for testing purposes and some wishful coding

Comment: there. what do i do now?

Comment: duplicate to users other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14971233/1606972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
conn.Open()
Dim comm As New SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE reparatii ADD durata_executie INT", conn)

comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I would also suggest using a `using` statement to automatically dispose of objects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376068/does-end-using-close-an-open-sql-connection

Comment: and a rather fine suggestion. i was trying to immitate an example and i became confused when autocomplete didnt give me the execute non query method. using would have solved that i guess, it all makes sense now