# Accessing table and column comments in Oracle for tables in SQL Server via databaselink

Tags: sql-server, oracle, comments, database-link

I use an Oracle database, where I have a database-Link to a Microsoft SQL Server database.
I need to access the comments for tables in the Microsoft SQL Server database from my Oracle database.

Using the script below I get the values for owner, table_name and column_name, but my comments field is empty (null), although there should be comments.

Why can't I query the comments?

```
select owner, table_name, table_type, comments
from all_tab_comments@DB_LINK_SQL_SERVER;

select owner, table_name, column_name, comments
from all_col_comments@DB_LINK_SQL_SERVER;
```

Comment: I would be surprised if that oracle-specific function was aware of the extended properties used in SQL Server. If correct, then you need TSQL specific syntax.

Answer (score 0):

ALL_TAB_COMMENTS and ALL_COL_COMMENTS are Oracle views. They have no knowledge of SQL Server tables. You would need to create a view on SQL Server. See Stackoverflow [SQL Server: Extract Table Meta-Data (description, fields and their data types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types) and [Accessing table comments in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082755/accessing-table-comments-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hey! Thanks, yes, I guess creating a view in SQL Server that I then query via Oracle is the way to go.
I'm just wondering why it's possible to query owner, table_name and column name from ALL_TAB_COMMENTS and ALL_COL_COMMENTS, but not comments.

Comment: @PercivalPersephi Ok, you left me curious with that last comment, so I tried to find out what is going on. I traced a session where I `SELECT *   FROM all_tab_comments@hssql520.world` . The underlying call was to an undocumented table function `sys.hs$_ddtf_opttables `. The comments are coming from "remarks" column `CAST (t.remarks AS VARCHAR2 (4000)) comments`. I tried adding a variety of extended properties to the SQL Server table (COMMENT, COMMENTS,MS_Description', remarks) but could not get  a return value for comments.