# How to copy data from source database table to its corresponding target database table dynamically with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So basically I have a table that looks like this. I have to migrate data from source database tables to its corresponding target database tables.

```
    SourceTableName                    DenormalizedU4SMTable             TargetTableName

1)  Lookup_AcademicTimeType                Time                          ACTimeType
2)  Lookup_TimeDurationType                Time                          ACTimeDurationType
3)  TimeStructure_ACAcademicTime           Time                          ACAcademicTime
4)  TimeStructure_AdmissionsTime           Time                          AdmissionsTime
5)  TimeStructure_BillingTime              Time                          BillingTime
```

Now i want to iterate through each row of this table in such a way that so I can copy the data from **Lookup_AcademicTimeType** to **ACTimeType**. So the target database tables have some extra columns like **Create Date, ModifyDate**, etc.

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (HERE I WANT TO AUTOMATICALLY BRING ALL COLUMN OF SPECIFIC TARGET TABLE)
    SELECT *, **THOSE EXTRA COLUMN** 
    FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

I can do this one by one for each table but i want to do this dynamically for all the tables in one go. Can anyone tell me how i can do this??

Comment: Please add a tag about the database product you are using. Have you tried `INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE SELECT **columns** FROM SOURCE_TABLE`? It may work if the columns in the select corresponds to ALL columns in the target.

Comment: Hi I'm using SQL Server 2016. I did this for each table one by one, but i want to know how i can do this dynamically? For all tables? And also how i can put the name of the columns in the insert statement?   @Conffusion

Comment: If you want to generate SQL for all tables, all columns I would suggest to write a stored procedure which uses the metadata table to loop over all tables and columns to generate the SQL statements. I don't know SQL Server but there must be a way to retrieve the meta data of your tables (sysobjects?). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types